# Which is more correct: participant list, participants list or participants' list?

Tags: word-choice

Which is more correct: participant list, participants list or participants' list? The context is a list of participants in a course.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=participant+list%2Cparticipants+list%2Cparticipants%27+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparticipant%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparticipants%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparticipants%20%27%20list%3B%2Cc0) show that all are used, the ratio at the moment seeming to be 7 : 4 : 1 (re your ordering). The previous questions indicate that all are equally 'grammatical', that the apostrophe is becoming old-fashioned in such cases where true ownership isn't involved, and that the singular attributive ....

Comment: is the preferred choice unless there is perceived to be an overriding need to stress plural participants / associates / ....